# agda: How do I tell the type system that two types are equal?

Tags: agda

Say I have type dependent on Nat

```
data MyType : (i : ℕ) → Set where
  cons : (i : ℕ) → MyType i
```

and a function:

```
combine : {i₁ i₂ : ℕ} → MyType i₁ → MyType i₂ → MyType (i₁ ⊔ i₂)
```

Now I'm trying to write a function:

```
create-combined : (i : ℕ) → MyType i
create-combined i = combine {i} {i} (cons i) (cons i)
```

Unfortunately, I get the error message:

```
i ⊔ i != i of type ℕ
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  MyType (i ⊔ i)
matches the expected type
  MyType i
```

I know I can prove `i ⊔ i ≡ i`, but I don't know how to give that proof to the type system in order to get this to resolve.

How do I get this to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subst` from `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`.

You give it:

- the proof that `i ⊔ i ≡ i`
- the dependent type that should be transformed with the proof, in your case `MyType`
- the term to be transformed, in your case `combine {i} {i} (cons i) (cons i)`

Or you can use the `rewrite` keyword as well on your proof, which is usually to be preferred.

Here is an (artificial) example of both possibilities applied on vector concatenation:

```
module ConsVec where

open import Data.Vec
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

_++₁_ : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {m n} → Vec A m → Vec A n → Vec A (n + m)
_++₁_ {m = m} {n} v₁ v₂ = subst (Vec _) (+-comm m n) (v₁ ++ v₂)

_++₂_ : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {m n} → Vec A m → Vec A n → Vec A (n + m)
_++₂_ {m = m} {n} v₁ v₂ rewrite sym (+-comm m n) = v₁ ++ v₂
```